# Displaying checkboxes one below the other in a laptop view does not work

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to display two checkboxes exactly one below the other in the laptop view. For this I use TailwindCss. I use the following code. The problem can be seen in the picture numbers. In the laptop view (md/lg) the `space-x-0` is not taken into account. What do I have to change?

```
  <div className="flex justify-center  flex-row md:flex-col space-x-2 md:space-x-0">
      <Checkbox
        value="gas"
        size="md"
        color="primary"
        onChange={() => handler("gas")}
        isSelected={gasSelected}
      >
        Gas
      </Checkbox>

      <Checkbox
        value="strom"
        size="md"
        color="primary"
        onChange={() => handler("strom")}
        isSelected={stromSelected}
      >
        Strom
      </Checkbox>
```

Laptop view:

[image]

Mobile view:

[image]